# How to move/drag an entire android view that contains a bunch of shapes inside?

Tags: android, view

I know how to drag a Ball around by extending View and overriding OnDraw and then calculating the new coordinates and redrawing my Ball.
What if I have hundreds of shapes inside that view and need the entire view moved around with all the shapes together.  Recalculating for every single shape doesn't seem feasible.
On the Iphone I can draw a bunch of things inside a view and then move the entire view and it takes care of drawing the things inside the view for me.  I only have to recalculate the coordinates of the view and then set the position not for everything inside the view.
Is that possible on Android?

Thanks,
Steven

Comment: Doesn't Android do the calculation for us? if you do invalidate() on the View, and then you override it's onDraw method to draw at the new location? as the hierarchy of views inside this one is attached to it, it should work? (only suggesting what seems logical to me,no certainty)

Comment: So you are saying that I should have a view inside a view?
Right now I do invalidate() and override OnDraw but inside OnDraw you have to do your drawing manually all over again giving it new coordinates and if I have hundreds of things to draw I would have to give new coordinates to everything I draw in that view.
As far as I know overriding OnDraw puts you in total control of drawing the view.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Canvas.translate()` method to offset everything being drawn within your `onDraw()` handler.

Track the translation offsets based on cursor movement or whatever, and use those offsets in your call to `translate()`.

You can do a similar effect with `Canvas.scale()` to handle pinch-zoom.

Don't forget to `save()` and `restore()` to put the `Canvas` back to its original state!

If you just want to move a view around within another view, simply adjust the top/left properties and call `Invalidate()`.  If it is a complex layout, do everything within a `RelativeLayout` and use the `LayoutParams` to position everything.